# autocomplete : Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to do an autocomplete using php and jQuery. I am using this tutorial: https://daveismyname.blog/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui

I tried different solution but I keep getting this two errors no matter what I try.

[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (search.php, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/autocomplete-master/search.php?term=a. Preflight response is not successful

I guess it comes from my request to my data base but I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Here s my code

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'demo');


if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['country'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}


?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you include the javascript bit that does the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thank you for your answer.
Here is my html file with my java code, hoping it's what you were hoping for.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body> 

    <form action='' method='post'>
        <p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1
    });             

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks again for your help.
Arthur.